# Who is productive Model.prototype.save() or Model.create()?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I use mongoose i have to save one documentConservation should be as fast as possible.

I know two ways Model.prototype.save() or Model.create().

What to choose ? Model.prototype.save() or Model.create().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really, matter `create` uses `save` internally. The [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.create) for `Model.create()` state:

> Shortcut for saving one or more documents to the database. MyModel.create(docs) does new MyModel(doc).save() for every doc in docs.